# One AngularJS IIS Web Site on a server connects to the WebAPI but an identical site doesn't

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I have an AngularJS website on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CoolWebSite and it connects to my C# based WebAPI successfully. I can tell the WebAPI is succesfully connected because on the main page there is a dropdown which is populated with data returned from WebAPI.

When I make an *exact copy* of the website on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CoolWebSite2 (files are copypasta'd) the WebAPI does not get successfully connected. The dropdown is empty. No console errors either.

What would be some reasons this second identical site doesn't work?

Suggestion 1: Site Bindings:

[image: Site bindings for the default website]

---

I probably don't have enough info here but I don't know what I don't know. Feel free to suggest more info and I'll nab it.

Comment: You copied the binaries, but site bindings for the second site might be incorrect.

Comment: @LexLi how would they be incorrect if I copied and pasted the 2nd site from the 1st one? Unless I'm misunderstanding how site bindings work....

Comment: The binding you showed above can only be used in one site (*:80:). If two sites have this binding, one of them would fail.